# Можно ли добавить путь к css для отдельного div/формы

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, внедряю форму заказа на страницу, у формы свой form.css с парой сотен стилей. После внедрения стили формы и сайта начинают пересекаться. Можно ли указать для отдельного div файл стилей, который он должен использовать?

Искал в гугле, но не нашел ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте для формы уникальный класс и допишите его в form.css, стили пересекаться не будут.

Comment: Да хоть для каждого отдельного элемента на сайте можно прописывать стили в отдельный `file.css`, правда это уже на пределами разумного....  Можно!!!!!!!